# Part[] for multi-index array

Tags: list-manipulation, index

If I want to set element (i,j) of two-dimensional array X to 0, I can write `X[[i,j]] = 0`. My question is how can I achieve this if I have the indices i and j in a list.

If `k = {i,j}`, writing `X[[k]] = 0` does not have the same effect, because it changes the ith and jth elements to zero separately. There are some obvious work-arounds. I could write
`X[[k[[1]],k[[2]]]] = 0`,
but that is both clunky and doesn't generalise automatically to higher-dimensional matrices. I could also write
`X = ReplacePart[X, {k->0}]`,
but this is also clunky, and it wastes memory by creating another copy of X.

Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: `x[[Sequence@@k]]=0;`

Comment: Ah, of course---thank you!

Comment: I may have been too hastily with closing as you need something more than expression manipulation. Let me know if you diagree with closing.